# How to return data on selection of multiple rows in React material ui table?

Tags: reactjs

/*
Details : 
I am looking for a way to implement table in such a way that
I can add or remove the data on click or selection of row.
Also can we use native js events in the material - ui
Also, if any library is there, please share as soon as possible.

*/

Comment: Please add some code to show what you tried so far and your progress. Check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to create well-asked questions.

Answer (score 0):

Map over the table row data and add a prop for `this.handleEdit.bind(this, data.id)` and `this.handleRemove.bind(this, data.id)`. Then in those functions, use the id to make an api call to update or delete the row.

Comment: I need it for material-ui react

Comment: @VasuKumar You're being downvoted because you aren't posting any of your own code attempts. I can't help you anymore than this without code examples.